# what is password with new installation

Tags: password

What is the password to switch user to root. I just put the new ad card into rpi3b and in trying to su root I am asked for a password and I enter raspberry and get authentication error.

Comment: You CAN  create a `root` password, as @joan suggested - however there is no need. Most of the experienced users DO NOT do this, but run commands with `sudo` when root access is needed.

Answer (score 5):

`root` user on Raspbian doesn't have a valid password at all. This is an intentional security measure which prevents someone from logging in as `root` to your board. Raspbian comes with a default `pi` user who has a password `raspberry`; once you change that password your RPi gets some basic security. Having a default `root` password would require you to change passwords for both users in order to secure your RPi.

You can set `root` password by running **`sudo passwd`**. This is only recommended if you want to play with login scripts of your `pi` user or `sudo` settings - having a `root` password will enable you to login and rescue your system if you accidentally lock yourself out of your `pi` account or break `sudo` (the latter specifically can only be fixed if you login as `root`). Otherwise I wouldn't do it.

Comment: *"in Linux a user without a password isn't allowed to login at all"* -> Not quite.   Depending on how `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are set-up, you can have a user with no password who can login by entering an empty password, or a user with no password who cannot login with any password.  If you want to try the former with `root`, edit `/etc/shadow` and remove the asterisk from between the first set of colons, so that line begins `root::`.  You can now login as root with no password.  See `man 5 shadow`.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks, I have (hopefully) fixed my answer by removing the wrong part.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly there is no root password by default.

If you want to login as root try

```
sudo su # login as root

passwd # set-up a root password
```

Comment: There's always a root user; pretty sure it's the only one that must exist.  Although in a sense that might not be true if UID 0 is always presumed to be valid.  Anyway, there is an explicit `root` on Raspbian, just password logins are disabled by default.

Comment: @goldilocks Yes, I was lax with my terms.

Answer (score -2):

I tried different passwords then finally password is: raspberry